# Retrieving information from HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I defined a hashmap as follows

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> hashmap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

I can get its content out by doing

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> keys = hashmap.entrySet();
for (Map.Entry<String,List<String>> entry : hashmap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey(); 
    List<String> thing = entry.getValue();
    System.out.println (key);
    System.out.println (thing);
}
```

However, I would like to know:

- How could I retrieve its content to an ordinary string?
- Is it possible to access the strings on the fly? (without doing (1)) I mean, the same way you do `string[0]`, etc
- Where is the length of the list stored?

Comment: 1) Which info are you referring to? ... 2) You mean like using a string array? ... 3) `hashmap.size()`? Or do you want to have the length of `List<String>`?

Comment: ad 2): A `HashMap` is not ordered, so it makes no sense to access it by index.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You can do map.toString(), and you'll get a textual representation of the whole map, if that's what you want. Your second question doesn't make sense to me. A Map is not an array, and you can't access its elements as if it were one. The length of the list is stored in the list. You can access it by calling size() on the list, as on every other collection. The javadoc is your friend.

Comment: `HashMap.entrySet().toArray();` returns all Entries as an Array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: HashMap.entrySet().toArray(); does not work, it returns [Ljava.lang.Object;@adfd045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of **manually** getting the set of keys, how about using the `keySet()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet()) on the HashMap object from Java?

Use of `keySet()` looks like:

```
Set<String> keys = hashmap.keySet();
```

For the third bullet, see the `size()` [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#size()).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `String key = "str";` exists in the map. You can:

```
int mapSize = hashmap.size(); // get the map's size
List<String> list = hashmap.get("str"); // get a list for a key
String first = hashmap.get("str").get(0); // get a string in a list
int listSize = hashmap.get("str").size(); // get the size of a list
char ch = hashmap.get("str").get(0).charAt(0); // get a char of a string in a list in the map
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't have to know what are the keys named

Comment: @Peter then you can get the set of key using the `keySet()` method. Then loop over the set and determine what you want about the lists of strings.

Comment: How could that be done? I don't have much experience with maps

Comment: @Peter see my answer